# My ui flutter doesnt updated after adding list

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface

I have a list that called ActivityListData

```
static List<ActivityListData> tabIconsList = <ActivityListData>
```

and I have function to add new data

```dart
void createActivityWateringListData(int liter) {
  ActivityListData newData = ActivityListData(
    titleTxt: 'Watering',
    liter: liter,
    Time: '',
    startColor: '#0000FF',
    endColor:  '#1E90FF',
  );

  ActivityListData.tabIconsList.add(newData);

}
```

if I add manually in List it will be shown in ActivityHistory in this picture
[image: Activity History]

but if I use function createActivityWateringListView it will not updated

```
 }) async {
return showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (_) => InputWateringDialog(
    cancelText: cancelText,
    okText: okText,
    title: title,
    createActivityWateringListData: (value) {
      ActivityListData newData = ActivityListData(
        titleTxt: 'Watering',
        liter: value,
        Time: '',
        startColor: '#0000FF',
        endColor: '#1E90FF',
      );
      ActivityListData.tabIconsList.add(newData);
    },
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: Where are you showing the contents of the list? Are you using a StatefulWidget?

Comment: use StatefulBuilder inside ur Showdialog like this--->showDialog( context: context, builder: (context) => StatefulBuilder(builder: (context,setState) => InputWateringDialog()